# Checking out a Heroku app

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Probably a n00b question, but I am new to Heroku. Here goes:

Using the heroku osx command-line utility, how do I checkout a specific app that already exists on the server? it comes from another developer so I never checked it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app). Here's the relevant command:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a myapp
```